# Проблемы с PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

При открытие проекта, пдключенные библиотеки django подчеркиваются красным цветом. Зашел в File>Settings>'Python Interpreter'. Внизу окна увидел сообщение 'Python packaging tools not found. Install packaging tools'. Я подумал, что при поиске библиотек django интерпретатор не находит их. В списке интерпретаторов pyhton я удалил все. После добавил новую виртуальную среду (это было решением в видео), но ничего не изменилось. Что подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Возможно у вас отсутствует `pip`. Установить его можно [здесь](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)
2. Также возможен данный вариант решения вашей проблемы : от `settings` (перейти к) → `project Interpreter`. Нажмите кнопку + в правом верхнем углу, и вы получите всплывающее окно доступных пакетов. Затем найдите пакет packaging python.
   Затем нажмите "Установить пакет", чтобы установить пакет.

Comment: pip установлен.
При нажатии на + ничего не происходит.

Comment: @borrya , переустанавливать pycharm пробовали? И если у вас linux , попробуйте это : `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: команду выше выполнял, переустановка также не помогла.

Comment: @borrya , пробовали устанавливать `packaging` модуль? Также просмотрите данную ссылку : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911183/windows-pycharm-failed-to-install-python-packaging-tools?rq=1